# Display special characters using System.out.println

Tags: java, database, string, character-encoding, system.printing

I'm having trouble sending or displaying text with special characters from my webservice to my database. On my eclipse I have set the character encoding to UTF-8 but it still doesn't let me display the characters. For example a simple print like the code below

```
String test ="привет"; 
System.out.println(test);
```

OR

```
String test ="привет";
String query = "insert into communication (`test`) VALUES ('"+ test +"');
PreparedStatement preparedStmt1 = con.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStmt1.executeUpdate();
```

The result on the console and if I send this to my database is ??????. How do I get this to display correctly on the console and hopefully in the database

Comment: Is this the eclipse console, or sh/cmd? what character set is your console set to?

Comment: eclipse, if by console character set you mean the settings in Windows > Preferences > WorkSpace it is set to UTF-8. Is there another way to set the console separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, its the XXI. century and we're still struggling with things like character encoding...

My first guess is that either:

1. your source file encoding might be wrong (do you use build tools like Maven? It might be needed to set the source-encoding there too),
2. your console encoding might be wrong (are you under Windows? The default command line console is not UTF by default, its local-dependant, but with a small play in the registry you can set its encoding)
3. your DB encoding might be incorrect (what is the Table encoding, can you check that?)

Comment: I've set the table encoding to utf8 still the same result. As far as  the encoding goes I can display special characters on when I program in android.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using Eclipse, then

1. right click on you project.
2. Go to Properties
3. Select UTF-8 in "Text
   File Encoding "

[image]

Answer (score 10):

See if this works.

```
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
    out.println(test);
```

For storing in DB, use following to explicitly encode the string in UTF-8

```
String newString = new String(test.getBytes(), "UTF8");
```

Comment: No, I get the same characters

Comment: you must encode the string to "iso-8859-1" ex: new String(test.getBytes(), "iso-8859-1");

Answer (score 0):

may be you need to decode your character string to ISO-8859 first and then encode it to UTF-8

Comment: if it is maybe, you should add it as a comment rather answer.