# Unable to encode the Romanian Characters

Tags: java

I have a requirement to read the Properties file with Strings having Romanian Characters.

When I try to do the encoding, I see some of the characters are not encoded properly.

```
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("view.Country");
    Enumeration keys = bundle.getKeys();
    while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = (String) keys.nextElement();
        String value = bundle.getString(key);
        try {
            System.out.println(key + ": " + new String(value.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"));
            System.out.println("-----------");
            System.out.println(key + ": " + new String(value.getBytes("Windows-1250"), "Windows-1250"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Input:

```
Country=România
AdministrativeAreaType=Țara
```

Output:

```
AdministrativeAreaType: ?ara
-----------
AdministrativeAreaType: ?ara
Country: România
-----------
Country: România
```

As you can see in the output, the country value is encoded properly. But the AdministrativeAreaType value is not encoded properly.

Please let me know if there is anything wrong in the code.

Comment: one reason. the input file is not UTF-8 or UNICODE. and on another note have you tried ResourceBUndle with Locale. Like in this example http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-locales-and-resource-bundles-to-internationalize-my-application.html

Comment: A ResourceBundle file is always in ISO-8859-1 encoding. You probably saved the file in a different encoding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use UTF-8 in resource properties with ResourceBundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle)

Comment: Also please check this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933620/display-special-characters-using-system-out-println

Answer (score 1):

As other fellow members of the community suggested, Romanian is not a language supported by UTF-8 or UNICODE.

I would recommend having a look at the list of [Supported Encodings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html). Romanian should be covered by [ISO-8859-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2).

I am not sure, but I am guessing you will be required to make the conversion yourself.